# second partial derivatives of $f(z)=\arctan ((x+y)/(1-xy))$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $$f(x,y)=\arctan \frac {x+y}{1-xy}.$$

So it is my intention to find out what second partial derivative $f_{xx}$, $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yy}$ are. But using quotient rule turns out to be complex.

Is there any easy way to calculate second partial derivative?

Comment: I'm no master of Calculus but I don't see any other method than the Quotient rule to go about this. Maybe someone else can shed a light.

Comment: Note that $\arctan \frac {x+y}{1-xy}=\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)$.

Comment: Ah, trigonometry :) Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add a caveat to Algin's excellent hint. The equality
$$\arctan \frac {x+y}{1-xy}=\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)\tag{1}$$
is true when $xy<1$. When $xy>1$, the two sides differ by $\pi$: for example, with $x=2=y$ we have $\arctan (-4/3) = 2\arctan 2-\pi$. When $xy=1$, the left side of (1) is undefined.

The computation of derivatives is not affected much: 
$$f_{xx}(x,y)=(\arctan x)'', \ f_{yy}(x,y)=(\arctan y)'', \ f_{xy}(x,y)=0$$ 
provided that $xy\ne 1$. At the points with $xy=1$ the function $f$ is not continuous and does not have partial derivatives.